# how to copy from ISKSurface to TSHPaintBox in Skia for Delphi

Tags: delphi-11-alexandria, skia

I want to convert a program which uses a `Tbitmap` and a `TImage` and instead use `Skia` for Delphi so that the drawings are antialiased.

The bitmap was drawn on and when complete it was copied to the image using `image.canvas.copyrect`.

To reproduce this I have tried using an `ISKSurface` instead of a `TBitmap`, and an `TSkPaintBox` instead of a `TImage`.

If I draw directly onto the paintbox canvas the `antialiasing` works fine, but when I draw to the ISKsurface and then copy to the TSKPaintboxe the result is not antialialsed.

```
 procedure TfrmMain.drawTest(canvasA: ISkCanvas; targetRect: TRectF);
var
  paint: ISkPaint;
  LSurface: ISKSurface;
  LFont1:ISkFont;
  LTypeface:ISkTypeface;
  rot:single;
  tempimg:ISKImage;
  RWidth,RHeight:integer;
  
begin
  RWidth := round(targetRect.Right);
  RHeight := round(targetRect.Height);

  LSurface := TSkSurface.MakeRaster(RWidth, RHeight);//


  // Set canvas color
  LSurface.canvas.drawColor(TAlphaColors.Aqua);
  LSurface.canvas.Clear(TAlphaColors.Aqua); // refresh canvas

  paint := TSKPaint.Create;
  Paint.SetColorF(TAlphaColorF.Create(TALphaColorRec.Blue));
  paint.AntiAlias := true;
  paint.StrokeWidth := 1;
  paint.Style := TSkPaintStyle.Stroke; // .fill .strokeandfill

  LSurface.canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, 200, 700, paint);
  LSurface.canvas.drawcircle(500,500,200,paint);

  LTypeface := TSkTypeface.MakeFromName('Arial',tskFontStyle.normal);
  LFont1 := TSkFont.Create(LTypeface, 66, 1);
  LFont1.Edging := TSkFontEdging.AntiAlias;
  Paint.Style := TSkPaintStyle.Fill;
  rot := -90;
  LSurface.canvas.Rotate(rot);
  LSurface.canvas.DrawSimpleText('234.4', -500,500,LFont1,paint);
  LSurface.canvas.Rotate(-rot);
  LSurface.canvas.DrawSimpleText('789', 500,500,LFont1,paint);
  
  tempimg := lsurface.MakeImageSnapshot; //only way I can see to get a oopy of
                                         //LSurface.canvas to TSKPaintBox.canvas
  
  canvasA.DrawImageRect(tempimg,targetRect,targetRect); //result is not antialiased.



end;
```

Could someone please tell me where to find information on what I should have read or what I am doing wrong.

Update: If I save the snapshot to a png image the png is antialiased. So I imagine the problem is some scaling problem copying from the LSKSurface.canvas to the TSKPaintBox.